# IF EXISTS does not drop the temp table

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

This is probably a multipart question:

When I issue the statment

```
IF OBJECT_ID('temp..#tablename) IS NOT NULL --drop the table here
```

it does not drop the temp table. When I go look at the temp db, the name is something totally different...

```
#tablename___________________________________________00000001069F
```

Obviously, the drop statement wont work with this. How can I make sure that the temp table gets dropped with the above statement.

Also, if I use the "USE dbName" before the create temp table statement, does the temp table still get created in tempdb or the the dbName database? Is the default always tempDb?

Thanks,
RV.

Comment: SO would not let me post the drop statement here. Probably to prevent injection attacks. But no issues.

Comment: Your' missing a ' after the table name in your Object_ID

Comment: yeah..Probably happened while editing the code on this page. But thats not the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use should use

```
OBJECT_ID('tempDB..#tablename')
```

not

```
OBJECT_ID('temp..#tablename')
```

> does the temp table still get created in tempdb or the the dbName database? Is the default always tempDb?

YES

Temp Tables always gets created in TEMPDB..

Reason why you are seeing name like `_____00000001069F` is due to the fact that Temp tables are session specific and SQL takes care of assigning names to them,so that names won't conflict,even when they are used in parallel sessions with same names

Look out this answer on DBA.SE for more info,specifically look out Temp Tables section :

[What's the difference between a temp table and table variable in SQL Server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server)

Comment: missing single quote, should be...  `OBJECT_ID('tempDB..#tablename')`

Comment: Cool. I will go ahead and add a drop statement at the end of my script so that I make a clean exit and release the memory at the end. No point in checking for it it in the beginning if its only session based. Thanks again for the explanation.

Comment: Turns out, as soon as I changed the temp to tempDB, the DROP statement worked fine.